# Java Swing : Jtable Highlight ONLY part of a word in a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Hi this question is rather specific. For class we had to make some kind of library program.

I made my list displayed in a JTable and ive implemented a search window that also uses a JTable...I Made a custom CellRenderer to Highlight when the term search was contained in the Code of the book or the Title.

My question is right now it bold the WHOLE word....is it possible to make it only bold part of that word ?

right now ill also have in that class a function that gives me the indexes of start and end of the search term in the value of the cell. (find it at the end of the class under getSearchIndex(Object, String) )

here is a screen and below the code for the renderer (the one for colors is separate).

[image: Sorry this is in French]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

 class HighlightRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String searched = "";

public HighlightRenderer(String search){
    super();

    if(search != null && search != "")
        searched = search;
    else searched = "";
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
    Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if(searched.length() == 0){
            cellComponent.setFont(new Font(this.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, this.getFont().getSize()));
        }

        else if(value.toString().toUpperCase().contains(searched.toUpperCase())){
            cellComponent.setFont(new Font(this.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, this.getFont().getSize()));
            int[] index = getSearchIndex(value, searched);
        }

    return cellComponent;
}

private int[] getSearchIndex(Object value, String search){

    int searchLength = search.length();
    String key = (String) value;

    int[] retour = new int[2];
    retour[0] = -1;
    retour[1] = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++){
        if(key.substring(i, i+searchLength).equalsIgnoreCase(search)){
            retour[0] = i;
            retour[1] = i + searchLength;
            return retour;
        }
    }
    return retour;

}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any tip or tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text components can have a StyledDocument and have parts of the text marked by specifying color attributes.

A bit cheaper is to use HTML. Any text component, like the JLabel what the cell renderer offers by default. The HTML can be very partial.

```
JLabel label = (JLabel) cellComponent; // Or new JLabel();
label.setText(
    "<html>An <span style='background-color: lightskyblue'>example</span> of HTML");

String highlight(String text, String sought) {
     text = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML4(text); // <, >
     sought = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML4(sought);
     return "<html>" + text.replace(sought, "<b>" + sought + "</b>");
}
```

Comment: You could just use `setText` directly on the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, it'd be the same thing without the need to cast first

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, DefaultTableCellRenderer is its own Component. In that respect some of the OP's code like `this.setFont` and `component.setFont` might act a bit surprisingly being the same.

Comment: But `Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent` is returning an instance of itself, so `cellComponent == this` is `true` :P, so in either case it will work, I'm just lazy ;)

Comment: The html doesnt seem to work....also the StringEscapeUtils probly needs some import i cant find....google cant help either i dont have the required libraries

Comment: @Ronin825 what did you actually do? I've tried adding the trailing </html> tag but even so it doesn't work.

Comment: @devoured elysium I closed this assignement a long time ago. But let me check my code and ill get back to ya !